# How to share a message from one channel to another?

Tags: go, slack-api

I'm looking for a way to let my Slack bot mimic what happens when I hit the right-arrow button on a channel message, like this:

[image: screenshot of "Share this message" pop-up]

If I hit "Share" on that window the original message will appear in the destination channel with the same message URL as the original (which is what I need).

I tried just posting the message URL by the bot but the URL appeared as a simple link, it didn't actually look like a copy of the original message.

How can I achieve this with a bot?

In case this matters, the bot is written in Go using https://github.com/nlopes/slack

EDIT: Here is a rough minimal code of what I tried (also tried surrounding the URL with `<>`, but got the same results):

```
s := slack.New(accessToken, slack.OptionDebug(true))
s.PostMessage(
    “#target-channel“,
     slack.MsgOptionText("https://organization.slack.com/archives/original-channel-id/original-msg-id”, false),
     slack.MsgOptionAsUser(false),
 )
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)‘s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite it‘s „harsh“ title.

Comment: It's far from being the first question I asked on StackOverflow. I describe what I'm trying to achieve, how I tried, the results I got and the technologies I use. What other information is missing?

Comment: You have not shown what you have tried so far (aka „da codez“ ;) ). It is pretty hard to find out why a link is sent instead of the content without seeing the code, isn‘t it?

Comment: Ok I'll add this when I get to a desk

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from a tip by Slack support - passing `slack.MsgOptionEnableLinkUnfurl()` to `PostMessage()` caused the message to be shared as I wanted.